# In web2py, when can javascript tell if all LOAD() components have been loaded?

Tags: ajax, web2py

In web2py I'm loading a whole set of separate forms into a single web page using `{{=LOAD(...)}}`. How can I fire up some javascript function when all these have initially finished loading? If I use `.ajaxStop()`, then the function is called later too, every time one of the form components is submitted, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: In the `.ajaxStop()` handler, have you tried calling `$(this).off('ajaxStop')` to turn off the handler after it is called the first time? Alternatively, I suppose you could keep count of the number of open Ajax requests, decrement the count as each completes, and trigger a handler when the number gets to zero.

Comment: Thanks. No I haven't tried that - the ajaxStop seemed a little bit of a hack to me, so was wondering if there was an alternative. But if you recommend that, then I'll go with it.

Comment: @Anthony, incidentally, this is so that each row of a database can be shown on screen and edited/submitted independently. This can all be done as part of a table, as long as the <form> element within each LOAD() component is treated as  a table-row in css, and the enclosing <div> is treated as a table-row-group. This seems like a nice use of LOAD, but I haven't seen it documented anywhere. Is it worth writing up?

Comment: I don't necessarily recommend `ajaxStop` -- just pointing out that it might be usable if you turn it off after you no longer need it. Doing something to explicitly tracking the loading of the components themselves might end up being more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a reasonable way for my use case, since each LOAD() event takes the sql table row id as a parameter. I define an empty global javascript object `loaded` early in the file, then fill in loaded=false properties when looping over each row:

```
    <script>var loaded = {};</script>
    {{for row in rows:}}
        <script>loaded['{{=row.id}}']=false</script>
        {{=LOAD('default','mycomponent.load', args=[row.id], ajax=True)}}
    {{pass}}
```

And as each `mycomponent.load` component is parsed, I flag it as loaded in the javascript array, and check for all loaded==true. E.g. at the end of the `mycomponent.load` file

```
<script>
    loaded['{{=row.id}}']=true; 
    if (Object.keys(loaded).every(function(k) {return loaded[k]}))
        function_to_execute_once_all_LOADs_done()
</script>
```